# How to create htaccess fiel in api link

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I created API by using PHP. 
My API link is

```
http://localhost/phpworkspace/api_testing/api.php
```

I want to clean my API link by using .htaccess file like

```
http://localhost/api/v1/retrieve.json
```

I created various htaccess file. But I can't get. How can I do that? Please help me kindly.

Comment: Is my answer is working for you?

Comment: Yes,It is OK for me.Thank you very much!.

Comment: please accept my answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Create `.htaccess` file in your `www` directory and paste the following code into the `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/v1/retrieve\.json$ /phpworkspace/api_testing/api.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do what you want

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/v1/retrieve.json$ /phpworkspace/api_testing/api.php [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

step 1 : On rewrite mod

step 2 : put code in .htaccess file

**.htaccess** file

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /api_testing

RewriteRule ^api/([.*]+)/$ /api_testing/api.php [L,QSA]